# Does rsyslog ignore any files under rsyslog.d that do not end in .conf?

Tags: rhel, rsyslog

The reason why I ask this is that I want to configure my deployment in a modular manner. I would have N number of text files where I can edit how rsyslog behaves in N number of cases, all of which would be located within the same directory but without the .conf extension. A script would rebuild the actual conf file that rsyslog.conf includes and restarts rsyslog to apply the configuration. That way I don't have to navigate a long configuration file when I can just edit the one file that has the configuration I want to modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what directive you have in the rsyslog.conf file.  Typically, it might be

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

which is a wildcard glob pattern that only includes files ending `.conf`. However, it is possible to have instead

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/
```

when all files (except those beginning `.`) will be included. Note, these are legacy directives, see [here](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/rainerscript/include.html) for the RainerScript equivalent command which is

```
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf")
```

and also allows you to specify a filename from an environment variable:

```
include(file=`echo $ENV_VAR`)
```